# c# - Asserting with OR condition

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assertions

i am checking a string for three characters

```
Assert.AreEqual(myString.Substring(3,3), "DEF", "Failed as DEF  was not observed");
```

the thing is here it can be `DEF` or `RES`, now to handle this what i can think of is the following

```
bool check = false;
if( myString.Substring(3,3) == "DEF" || myString.Substring(3,3) == "RED" ) 
check = true;

Assert.IsTrue(check,"Failed");
Console.WriteLine(""Passed);
```

**IS THERE a way i can use some OR thing within Assert**

p.s i'm writing unit test & yes i will use ternary operator instead....

Comment: can't you just put your if check inside the assert?..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Assert.IsTrue((myString.Substring(3,3) == "DEF" || myString.Substring(3,3) == "RED")?true:false,"Failed");
```

Comment: No need for the conditional operator here: `Assert.IsTrue(myString.Substring(3,3) == "DEF" || myString.Substring(3,3) == "RED","Failed");`

Comment: thanks for pointing it out,i put is as just for reference if anybody doesn't know it already

Answer (score 8):

Using NUnit, the [AnyOf constraint](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/AnyOfConstraint.html) works:

```cs
Assert.That(myString.Substring(3,3), Is.AnyOf("DEF", "RED"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the unit testing framework you are using you could do something like this:

```
Assert.Contains(myString.Substring(3, 3), new [] { "DEF", "RED" });
```

But beware, this is abusing the system a bit, because it switched *expected* and *actual*.

An alternative approach that should work with any framework and doesn't abuse the system would look like this:

```
Assert.True(new [] { "DEF", "RED" }.Contains(myString.Substring(3, 3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

NUnit also has an option to do your test via OR:

```
Assert.That(myString.Substring(3, 3), Is.EqualTo("DEF").Or.EqualTo("RED"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [xUnit](https://xunit.net/)

```
    var result = new[] { "DEF", "RED" };
    Assert.Contains(myString.Substring(3,3), result);
```