# How to user Assert in a conditional statement with two different elements

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit-3.0

I am new to using Selenium with C#, so this might be too easy for most of you. Also, I did search on this forum and couldn't get a satisfactory response, so will go ahead and ask the problem I am trying to solve.

I want to use **Assert** between two different elements to check for a value. If first element finds it I want to exit the loop and pass the test, or else the second element; otherwise fail the test if not found in both.

p0 is the string that I am passing in my test and I want to check that string is there either in **tranName** or **accName**

*transName* is int and *accName* is string. But I am assigning both to same var.

```
Assert.That(transName.Text.Equals(p0));
Assert.That(accName.Text.Equals(p0));
```

Can you please suggest, how best to deal with this.

Thanks..!!

Comment: Use an `if` statement?

Comment: Know that.. but how to?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using NUnit 3.0? If not please post what you are using. Have you looked at the docs? This seems like something that would be covered.

Comment: This is likely a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359284/c-sharp-asserting-with-or-condition

Comment: @JeffC Yes I am using NUnit framework, with Selenium C#

Answer (score 0):

```
transName = driver.FindElement(By.xxxx);

if(transName.Displayed) {
   Assert.That(transName.Text.Equals(p0));
}
else {
   accName= driver.FindElement(By.xxxx);
   if(accName.Displayed) {
     Assert.That(accName.Text.Equals(p0));
   }
   else {
     Assert.That(True.Equals(False))
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yong. Your piece of code got me started but the issue is that if my first condition is false the loop is not executing the second condition. Also, another bit I missed mentioning that my transName is int. So, I did a bit more research and used the logic as above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do all those conditionals. Here's an easier/shorter way to do this using LINQ, NUnit, and a custom CSS selector locator.

```
List<string> text = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#XXX, #YYY")).Where(e => e.Displayed).Select(e => e.Text).ToList();
CollectionAssert.Contains(text, p0);
```

Basically we combine the two locators into one where `#XXX` means an id of XXX and the comma is an OR operator. Selenium finds all the elements that match those two locators and then filters those down to those that are visible. Then it get the `.Text` of each of the visible elements and returns them as a `List`. The second line is NUnit where you can assert a `string` in a `List<string>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
int n;
bool searchWithNumber = int.TryParse(p0, out n);

var transName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("XXX"));
if (transName.Displayed && !searchWithNumber)
{
  Assert.That(tarnsName.Text.Contains(p0));
}
else if (searchWithNumber)
{
var accName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("YYY"));
if (accName.Displayed)
{
 Assert.That(accName.Text.Contains(p0));
}
else
{
  Assert.That(true.Equals(false));
   }
 }
```

So what I am doing above is. I am first parsing the *string p0* to extract number if it has, which I am then assigning to bool. Then in the loop I am first checking if the tranName has any number then skip to else if condition, if it has text then execute the first condition.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to explain what your code does and why it answers the question. Also fix your code indent.

Comment: The code does exactly what my question was about and now solves the condition

Comment: Your question doesn't mention 90% of what you have in this answer.

Comment: If I knew what I explained above to start with, I won't have asked the question in the first place. Your feedback is appreciated but not very helpful in this case...thanks anyways..!!